# How to get the longest word in txt file python

Tags: python, file, txt

```
article = open("article.txt", encoding="utf-8")
for i in article:
    print(max(i.split(), key=len))
```

The text is written with line breaks, and it gives me the longest words from each line. How to get the longest word from all of the text?

Comment: you need to change your code a bit. look that snippet -  https://replit.com/@marmeladze1/GiftedWarmheartedServerapplication#main.py

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to read the entire text file into a Python string, remove newlines, and then find the largest word:

```py
with open('article.text', 'r') as file:
    data = re.sub(r'\r?\n', '', file.read())

longest_word = max(re.findall(r'\w+', data), key=len)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
longest = 0
curr_word = ""
with open("article.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split(" "):  # Use line-by-line generator to avoid loading large file in memory
            word = word.strip()
            if (wl := len(word)) > longest:  # Python 3.9+, otherwise use 2 lines
                longest = wl
                curr_word = word
print(curr_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating through each line, you can get the entire text of the file and then split them using `article.readline().split()`

```
article = open("test.txt", encoding="utf-8")
print(max(article.readline().split(), key=len))
article.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways by which you could do that. This would work

```
with open("article.txt", encoding="utf-8") as article:
    txt =  [word for item in article.readlines() for word in item.split(" ")]
    
biggest_word = sorted(txt, key=lambda word: (-len(word), word), )[0]
```

Note that I am using a with statement to close the connection to the file when the reading is done, that I use readlines to read the entire file, returing a list of lines, and that I unpack the split items twice to get a flat list of items. The last line of code sorts the list and uses `-len(word)` to inverse the sorting from ascending to descending.

I hope this is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If your file is large enough to fit in memory, you can read all line at once.

```
file = open("article.txt", encoding="utf-8", mode='r')
all_text = file.read()
longest = max(i.split(), key=len)
print(longest)
```